# How do I monitor all incoming http requests?

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

I need to monitor my application from incoming http `POST` and `GET` requests originating from outside and sometimes inside the machine.

Is this possible?

Been using fiddler but this only does outgoing not incoming (from outside the machine) or have I configured it incorrectly?

This is for my web app that is meant to be receiving a `POST` from an external server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guys found the perfect way to monitor ALL traffic that is flowing locally between requests from my machine to my machine:

1. Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
2. When you need to capture traffic that is flowing from a localhost to a localhost then you will struggle to use wireshark as this only monitors incoming traffic on the network card. The way to do this is to add a route to windows that will force all traffic through a gateway and this be captured on the network interface.

   To do this, add a route with *`<ip address>`* *`<gateway>`*:

   ```
    cmd> route add 192.168.20.30 192.168.20.1
   ```
3. Then run a capture on wireshark (make sure you select the interface that has bytes flowing through it) Then filter.

The newly added routes will come up in black. (as they are local addresses)

Answer (score 67):

What you need to do is [configure Fiddler to work as a "reverse proxy"](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy)

There are instructions on 2 different ways you can do this on Fiddler's website.  Here is a copy of the steps:

---

**Step #0**

Before either of the following options will work, you must enable other computers to connect to Fiddler. To do so, click Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections and tick the "Allow remote computers to connect" checkbox. Then close Fiddler.

**Option #1: Configure Fiddler as a Reverse-Proxy**

Fiddler can be configured so that any traffic sent to `http://127.0.0.1:8888` is automatically sent to a different port on the same machine.  To set this configuration:

1. Start REGEDIT
2. Create a new DWORD named ReverseProxyForPort inside HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2.
3. Set the DWORD to the local port you'd like to re-route inbound traffic to (generally port 80 for a standard HTTP server)
4. Restart Fiddler
5. Navigate your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8888`

**Option #2: Write a FiddlerScript rule**

Alternatively, you can write a rule that does the same thing.

Say you're running a website on port 80 of a machine named WEBSERVER.  You're connecting to the website using Internet Explorer Mobile Edition on a Windows SmartPhone device for which you cannot configure the web proxy.  You want to capture the traffic from the phone and the server's response.

1. Start Fiddler on the WEBSERVER machine, running on the default port of 8888.
2. Click Tools | Fiddler Options, and ensure the "Allow remote clients to connect" checkbox is checked.  Restart if needed.
3. Choose Rules | Customize Rules.
4. Inside the OnBeforeRequest handler, add a new line of code:
   if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "webserver:8888") oSession.host = "webserver:80";
5. On the SmartPhone, navigate to `http://webserver:8888`

Requests from the SmartPhone will appear in Fiddler.  The requests are forwarded from port 8888 to port 80 where the webserver is running.  The responses are sent back through Fiddler to the SmartPhone, which has no idea that the content originally came from port 80.

Comment: Why is it so difficult? Surely there is a program that looks at all my network interfaces and just reads http packets. Cant seem to get wireshark or network monitor to do that,....

Comment: Wireshark is VERY powerful and I personally have only started to learn how to work with it in the past few months. I would be surprised to find out that it can't do something like this too.  It's probably just a matter of setting up the right filtering on the right interface.  I will post back another answer if I can figure out how to do it with Wireshark.

Comment: Hi Saul, did you read my response below. If you add a route within windows it forces all traffic out and then back in.

Comment: I read your answer and it makes sense for capturing localhost traffic with wireshark.  I guess I should point out that Fiddler is capable of capturing "localhost" traffic as well... but there is a catch.  You have to make your requests to the webserver using the hostname instead of the "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 loopback address.

Comment: @SaulDolgin How do we configure Fiddler if the web service runs on port 11000? like http://mywebserver:11000/mywebservice.asmx

Comment: I had to use `oSession.host.ToLower()` instead

Answer (score 34):

I would install Microsoft Network Monitor, configure the tool so it would only see HTTP packets (filter the port) and start capturing packets.

You could download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f)

Comment: wow, this is an awesome tool! I tried using Fiddler and setting remote proxy, but never succeeded. With network monitor I can see how my webservice is called and what the requests are.

Comment: I had same problem as above poster, was never able to get Fiddler working correctly.  MS network monitor tool worked like a champ though.

Comment: This tool worked well but I can't seem to inspect the payload for secure SSL calls. I get a `SSLApplicationData: Binary Large Object (304 Bytes)` message only. Is there any way to view this data?

Comment: SSL traffic are not supposed to be easily decryptable. Thats the intention of using SSL, to prevent eavesdroppers examining traffic. Anyway, there is a decrypt tool to do SSL decryption from MS Network monitor if you have the server SSL private key handy : http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/archive/2010/03/08/expert-to-decrypt-tls-ssl-traffic.aspx . Fiddler does this by using a fake certificate, effectively doing man-in-the-middle attack by ourselves.

Comment: "Network Monitor 3.4 is the archived version protocol analyzer and is no longer under development. Microsoft Message Analyzer is the replacement for Network Monitor 3.4."

Answer (score 13):

### Configure Fiddler as a 'reverse proxy' on Windows

(for Mac, see the link in Partizano's comment below)

I know there's already an answer suggesting this, however I want to provide the explanation and instructions for this that Telerik *should* have provided, and also cover some of the 'gotchas', so here goes:

### What does it mean to configure Fiddler as a 'reverse proxy'?

- By default, Fiddler only monitors *outgoing* requests from the machine on which you're running Fiddler
- To monitor *incoming* requests, you need to configure Fiddler to work as a 'reverse proxy'
- What this means is that you need to set Fiddler up as a 'proxy' that will intercept incoming http requests that are sent to a specific port (8888) on the machine where you want to listen to the incoming requests. Fiddler will then forward those requests to the web server on the same machine by sending them to the usual port for http requests (usually port 80 or 443 for https). It's actually very quick and easy to do!
- The standard way to set this up with Fiddler is to get Fiddler to intercept all request sent to Port '8888' (since this won't normally be used by anything else, although you could just as easily use another port)
- You then need to use the registry editor to get Fiddler to forward any http requests that Fiddler receives on port 8888, so that they're forwarded to the standard http port (port 80, port 443 for an https request, or another custom port that your web server is set to listen on)

**NOTE: For this to work, any request you want to intercept *must be sent to port 8888***

You do this by appending :8888 to your *hostname*, for example like this for an MVC route:

http://*myhostname*:8888/*controller*/*action*

---

## Walkthrough

### Ensure Fiddler can accept remote http requests on port 8888:

**Run Fiddler as administrator** Go to Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections, and ensure that 'Allow remote computers to connect' is checked, and 'Fiddler listens on port' is set to 8888:

[image]

**Configure Fiddler to forward requests received on port 8888 to port 80**

- Close Fiddler
- Start REGEDIT
- Create a new DWORD named ReverseProxyForPort inside HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2.

  - Now set the DWORD value to the local port you'd like to re-route inbound traffic to (generally port 80 for a standard HTTP server)
- To do this, right-click the DWORD you created and select 'Modify'. Ensure 'Base' is set to 'Decimal' and enter '80' (or another port) as the 'Value data':

### Ensure that port 8888 is opened on the firewall

- You must ensure that port 8888 is open to external requests (it won't be by default if your server is firewall-protected)

**That's it! Fiddler should now be set up as a reverse proxy, to intercept all requests from port 8888 (so that you can view them in Fiddler), and it will then forward them to your web server to actually be handled.**

### Test a request

- Restart Fiddler
- To test that Fiddler is intercepting external requests, open a browser *on the same machine where you've set up Fiddler as a reverse proxy*. Navigate your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8888
- This tests making a basic request to to port 8888
- You should see the request intercepted by Fiddler
- Now you can test a request from another machine, for example by making a request from a browser on another machine like this (where 'remoteHostname' is a hostname on the machine where you've set up Fiddler as a reverse proxy) :

http://*remoteHostname*:8888/*controller*/*action*

- Alternatively, you can compose a request by using another instance of Fiddler on a *remote* machine, using a URL similar to the one above. This will allow you to make either a GET or a POST request.

**IMPORTANT: Once you've finished viewing your request(s), go back to Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections and remove the 'Allow remote computers to connect' option, otherwise 3rd parties will be able to bounce traffic through your server**

Comment: In operating systems without REGEDIT (Window ahs  registry mac osx and linux don't) waht should be the equvalnt step?

Comment: I found it here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForMac

Answer (score 6):

**Microsoft Message Analyzer** is the successor of the Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4

If your http incoming traffic is going to your web server at 58000 port, start the Analyzer in Administrator mode and click new session:

use filter: tcp.Port = 58000 and HTTP

trace scenario: "Local Network Interfaces (Win 8 and earlier)" or "Local Network Interfaces (Win 8.1 and later)" depends on your OS

Parsing Level: Full

Answer (score 3):

You might consider running Fiddler as a reverse proxy, you should be able to get clients to connect to Fiddler's address and then forward the requests from Fiddler to your application.

This will require either a bit of port manipulation or client config, depending on what's easier based on your requirements.

Details of how to do it are here: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Help/ReverseProxy.asp

Comment: The link is moved to http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy

Answer (score 2):

Use [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) to see ports listening and connections. This will **not** give you the requests though.

In order to see requests, you need reverse of a proxy which I do not know of any such tools.

Use [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) to give you parts of the requests (first 1KB of the request).

Answer (score 2):

Using Wireshark..

I have not tried this:
http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

If that works, you could then filter for `http`/`http contains GET`/`http contains POST` traffic.

You might have to run two Wireshark instances, one capturing local, and one capturing remote. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com/), it has the built-in ability to display incoming HTTP requests and does not require any changes to the system configuration.

[image: HTTP Debugger]