# fiddler for all incoming requests?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have two web servers and installed fiddler in both. I just monitor all http requests those coming out side the web server that means requests those coming from the world.

I am able to request tracks when I open in web server local machine. How monitor other requests too those coming from outside the web server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I monitor all incoming http requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428680/how-do-i-monitor-all-incoming-http-requests)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Go to `Tools-->Fiddler Options` and make sure you have these options enabled:

[image]

If you have a proxy (untick the "Use PAC script")

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure Fiddler to work as a "reverse proxy"

check this: [Using Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Help/ReverseProxy.asp)