# Worklight: Service connection failed Dialog Box

Tags: service, connection, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing an unexpected issue that is when I am running App
most of the times a dialog box open up and saying **"Application failed

connection to the service** " See snapshot:

[image]

Though after two or three times pressing "**Reload**" button on this dialog connects App with WL Server and then App works fine. But if I kill App and then re-run it , again same dialog appears.

It also appears when you first time run App after installing on a device.

My App was running perfectly fine from two months back.

The only new thing that I have done is Push Notification. This is the
only new feature that I have added in the App.

Any suggestion on this?

1. What could be the root cause of this issue? How can I trace it?
2. And if I want to disable this dialog and instead show a
   custom message (alert) on screen. Because this dialog box reveals the
   running service / WL server URL.

In the console it only shows **"Application failed connection to the service** "

And while clicking on the Details option on the dialog box. It shows correct address of WL Server. And after three/four times of reload it connects App with server and then works fine, and afterwards goes fine and doesn't show anything.

The Logs are given below:

```
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp[2746] <Warning>: [LOG] ondeviceready event dispatched
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: {
        appVersionPref = "1.0";
        freeSpace = 13572620288;
        wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)";
        wlSkinName = default;
    }
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] Application did not define an i18n messages object, skipping translation.
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] wlclient init started
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] Read cookies: null
Apr 15 14:24:51 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
Apr 15 14:24:57 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] Connection went Down: Mon Apr 15 2013 14:24:57 GMT+0300 (AST)
Apr 15 14:24:57 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [ERROR] Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available.
Apr 15 14:25:07 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: [LOG] ondeviceready event dispatched
Apr 15 14:25:07 iPhone myApp [2746] <Warning>: {
        appVersionPref = "1.0";
        freeSpace = 13572620288;
        wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)";
        wlSkinName = default;
}
```

**by clicking Details:**

```
Apr 15 2013 23:55:17 GMT+0300 (AST)
Apr 15 23:55:17 iPhone myApp[3116] <Warning>: [ERROR] Client init failed. Connection to the service is not available.
Apr 15 23:55:19 iPhone myApp[3116] <Warning>: WLReachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
Apr 15 23:55:59 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[3120] Builtin profile: MobileSafari (sandbox)
Apr 15 23:56:02 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[3121] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
Apr 15 23:56:21 iPhone myApp[3116] <Warning>: Copied text: 'App Diagnostics

    Time : Mon Apr 15 2013 23:55:19 GMT+0300 (AST)
    Application Name : myApp
    Application Version : 1.0
    Service URL : https://www.mydomain.com.bh:443/AppProject/apps/services/api/myApp/iphone/
    Device Platform : iPhone
    Device Version : 6.1
    Screen Resolution : 320x480
    Airplane Mode : Not available
    Using Network : WIFI
    Wifi Name : Not available
    Mobile Network Type : Not available
    Carrier Name : Not available
    IP Address : 192.168.109.101
    Error Code : UNRESPONSIVE_HOST
    Error Message : Connection to the service is not available.
    HTTP Status :
```

Comment: Add useful information to your post. what is the error that is logged in server.log what then happens? what is the error you see in the Details table after tapping on the details button in the dialog?

Comment: Well sounds like a timeout that happens when the client tries to connect to the server... 1. try disabling push notifications, does it now always work OK? 2. add a description in your question of your init , what do you do there? something causes a timeout... 3. make sure nothing has changed in your network, that causes this.

Comment: (1) I dont know what changed on Network. (2) I will try by disabling Push (3) When App is starting it is using authentication challenger in the background to get connected with server and then Login Page appears where have to login and then using App. There is nothing special doing at the start up. As it is configured for Push, so you know how authentication challenger works at start up of the App. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when you click on `Details`? It should tell you why the connection failed.

Comment: @Marko see the Details log above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a network issue preventing you from connecting to your Worklight server.

This can be due to many different reasons, to list some:

- Poor WiFi/3G
- Faulty device
- Firewall issues on the network where the webserver is hosted
- Worklight server issue

To ensure that you are indeed reaching the server I would suggest using a network sniffer. One tool that runs on Windows is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler).

Fiddler can be set up as a reverse proxy where your device will be making calls to the proxy. The proxy will then route your request to the web server but it will also log the information so you can view it.

If you are on Windows, I would suggest installing Fiddler and following Option #2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428680/how-do-i-monitor-all-incoming-http-requests).

You should then be able to see if your requests are reaching the server and continue investigation from there.

Comment: It looks network issue but after three or four times of reload of App it connects successfully with the Server and then works fine afterwards. And during usage of App I never seen it had shown such dialog box. I am sure my client will not allow installing Fiddler or other tools but they can provide me network communication Logs. Now If i ask them for Logs then what I ask and how thing i should look for?thanks

Comment: Start by checking what your IP address is on your device then make a few requests, record the time and investigate the network logs to see whether all of your requests hit the server. Have you tried different devices and networks?

Comment: yes have tried different devices. Around 20 people from different countries are testing this App.