# Why would StreamReader.ReadLine do a better job of reading XML than XmlTextReader.Read?

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, readline, xmltextreader

I have this code which works fine from a Winforms app calling a Web API app (it successfully copies the XML file over to the server):

```
public static string SendXMLFile(string xmlFilepath, string uri, int timeout)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        if (timeout < 0)
        {
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
            request.Timeout = timeout;
        }

        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        try
        {
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = null; //<= uncomment for older versions of .NET
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //<= uncomment for older versions of .NET (comment out using)
            }
            finally
            {
                IDisposable disposableResponse = response as IDisposable;
                if (disposableResponse != null) disposableResponse.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            request.Abort();
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when trying to figure out why code that is as similar as possible to this working code is does not work when trying to send an xml file from a handheld device to the same server, I tried using XmlTextReader instead (as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557930/why-does-this-code-hang-on-reaching-the-first-readline-from-a-streamreader) ("*You are not using XML classes and methods here*"), where I go into detail about my travails with that); the only difference is that this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

...in the working (StreamReader) code was changed to this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilepath);
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an Element.
            sb.Append("<" + reader.Name);

            while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read attributes.
                sb.Append(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
            sb.Append(">");
            sb.Append(">");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            sb.Append(reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display end of element.
            sb.Append("</" + reader.Name);
            sb.Append(">");
            break;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

With the StreamReader code, the read data looks just as it does on disk:

[image]

With the XmlTextReader, though, it's all jumbled up like jambalaya shot out of a cannon at a herd of hippos:

[image]

...and the XmlTextReader version fails, with a "*The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.*"

So StreamReader.ReadLine works better with an XML file than XmlTextReader.Read does; seems strange...am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Look into XmlSettings. You have to tell the reader to format/indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the the `XmlTextReader` will ignore whitespace. You'll want to tell it specifically to include whitespace and also start to process whitespace in your switch.

Also note that all `XmlReader` implementations are disposable so wrap them in a `using`.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilepath, settings)) {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an Element.
                sb.Append("<" + reader.Name);

                while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read attributes.
                    sb.Append(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                sb.Append(">");
                sb.Append(">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: 
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                sb.Append(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display end of element.
                sb.Append("</" + reader.Name);
                sb.Append(">");
                break;
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Okay, if using is available in my older version of .NET that I'm using here, I'll try that.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, yes, `using` has always been available in C#. It's really important, you should be using `using` a lot, every time you create anything that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Well, then it's certain objects which are "usable" in newer versions of .NET that are not "usable" in older versions, because I've definitely run into that issue going between versions - I have to revert back to the neanderthalic way of coding when using older bits at times.